# Out putting birth years with TO_CHAR(M.DOB, 'YYYY')

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database with a store of members and dates of birth.

I am to "List name and year of birth of all members in alphabetical order by family name and given name with "DHDSJHDSDH" as parent

I currently have [Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6dqP.png)
Everything works apart from the birthdays as for someone with a birthday in 1993 it outputs 2093.

Comment: Hi sh ahern, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your actual code here, instead of an external image.

Comment: A reproducible test case would help.  If you're actually using the `YYYY` format mask, though, that implies that the data was inserted into the table incorrectly and the birth date was actually inserted as 2093 rather than 1993.

Comment: You can also extract the year with the year() function, assuming the DOB is actually one of the date data types.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you had code or table structure posted but I will take a stab. I would imagine you want something along the lines of:

```
SELECT FamilyName,
       GivenName,
       CONVERT(varchar, yearOfBirth, 101)
FROM schema.TableYouUse
ORDER BY FamilyName;
```

Like I said, this may not be what you are asking at all. What I did was query up the first name, last name, and birth date of the person in the table. I used CONVERT to make the birth date column varchar instead of DATETIME that way we can format it the way we like.

Notice that CONVERT takes parameters, the first param is target expression type, the second is the target date, and lastly we use 101 to format it the way you need. Here is a link to the convert docs for more styles you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Lastly, to address the crazy 2093 instead of 1993 that sounds like bad data entry to me.

Comment: I will edit with a photo to show that my data entry is fine as it shows as the correct year so I am confused

Comment: `convert` isa SQLServer function.  The question is tagged for Oracle which does not have a `convert` function.

Comment: Ah my bad I completely overlooked the oracle tag I was looking at sql tag. Too eager to help I guess.